# Cannot add node to Firebase through console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a Firebase project with 2 mobile apps:

1. FriendlyChat example from Firebase/Google (messages) - created first
2. Grocery Items list (grocery-items) - trying to create second

You can see the messages node already there with some test messages inside.

[image]

But when I try to add a child to the `appId` node, I give it a name "grocery-items" and I click on **ADD**, but the node does not get added.  It just disappears.

Why can't I add the grocery-items node?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The Firebase Database is a key-value store. It stores the values of keys at paths in the tree. But it only stores keys when they have an actual value. If there is no value for a key/path, it is immediately deleted.

So if you click the <kbd>+</kbd> button, then enter a key and click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button, it will delete the first key that you entered **because it doesn't have a value**.

What you instead should do depends on what you want to accomplish.

To add a single key/value pair:

- click the <kbd>+</kbd>
- enter a key/Name
- enter a Value
- click <kbd>Add</kbd>

If you want to add a JSON snippet/tree:

- click the <kbd>+</kbd>
- enter a key/Name
- click the <kbd>+</kbd> next to the (empty) Value
- enter a key/Name for the child
- enter a Value for the child
- click <kbd>Add</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!

Comment: Also, if you are unable to add items because you are blocked by "read-only" mode, you can just navigate to a url with the new node you want to add, and it will create the node for you. But as stated, you need to also add a value. "Navigate to the new prop that you want to add at the appropriate level. E.g. https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myapp-xxxxx/database/data/prop3 would create a new object prop3 at the root level and from there you can edit data at will." credit: https://medium.com/@justintulk/editing-data-in-firebase-when-blocked-by-read-only-non-realtime-mode-1ce103f178e5