# Firebase prevent Parent Deletion

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This might be a nosql thing that I am not aware of, but one issue I have found with the firebase realtime database, if a tree has all its children deleted, the parent will be deleted as well. Is there a way to stop this? and instead just have 'null' stored

Thanks!

Comment: Nope. As far as I'm aware, a key either has a non-null value or it does not exist.

Comment: The Firebase Database stores values at paths. If you store a value at a non-existent path, that path is auto-created. If you delete the last value at a path, that path is destroyed. There is no way to keep a path without a value in the Firebase Database. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800079/cannot-add-node-to-firebase-through-console/38800407#38800407), which is specifically about the console (where the same logic applies).