# how to structure a firebase database with ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an ionic app. I used the firebase login. Worked fine. Now I want to structure the database according to my class diagram. The thing is I am stuck at the first addition. I typed the name but in the value I don't know what to type. Being a student this is the first time I am using firebase database always used relational databases.

[image]

I understand that the first space is the name and in the 2nd space I put null, but it didn't appear.
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is a JSON database. This means it stores JSON values at paths. The values can be things like:

- Strings - `"Text"`
- Numbers - `42` or `3.1415`
- Booleans - `true` or `false`
- Objects - `{ "Other": { "Nested": "Objects", "Number": 123 } }`

To enter a data structure in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/) be sure to enter a value. If there is no value at a path, that path is automatically deleted.

Also see my step-by-step explanation here for the mechanics of entering data in the console: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800407

Answer (score 0):

In a NoSQL database as Firebase is, putting `null` as a value means that you actually are deleting it.

Hope it helps.