# Firebase : How to get other user's uid?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've made an chat app just for me and my friend.

When I message them, I want to store their `Uid`.

How do I do that ? Also mention if its needed to reconstruct the entire structure.

I have thought of `String[] uidList = DatabaseReference.child("Users").getKey();`

The **Messages** are not created yet. I want to create them with **friend_user_id** which I can't retrieve at this moment.

Below is how I want My Firebase Database structure to look like this :

```
app-id:

    Users:
        my_user_id:
            name:"Me"
            last_seen:"MyLastSeenTimeValue"

        friend_user_id:
            name:"Friend"
            last_seen:"FriendLastSeenTimeValue"

    Messages:

        my_user_id:
            friend_user_id:(How to retrieve this ?)
                random_msg_id_1:
                    text:"Hi"
                    msg_type:"text"
                    time:"msgTime"

                random_msg_id_2:
                    text:"Hello"
                    msg_type:"text"
                    time:"msgTime"

        friend_user_id:(How to retrieve this ?)
            my_user_id:
                random_msg_id_1:
                    text:"Hi"
                    msg_type:"text"
                    time:"msgTime"

                random_msg_id_2:
                    text:"Hello"
                    msg_type:"text"
                    time:"msgTime"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the `Json` output but as a guess, it should be something like following codes:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
       myRef.child("Messages").child("my_user_id").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for(DataSnapshot item_snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        // get the data here and loop through the friend_user_id to get the nodes like following
                        Log.d("User id ", item_snapshot.toString());

                    }
                  }

            @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                     // handle error
              }
});
```

Comment: @Monsen I want to get my friends id. In the activity I am able to get only `currendUserId = FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid();`

And I have updated the question with **correct** details.

Comment: Yes I get you. You can try using the codes I've just pasted in the answer. I know, you can get **only your Userid**  with that :) But, with mine, it will return the desired uid you want from the firebase output.

Comment: Thank you, I would be able to retrieve that. Can you tell how to put the `friend_user_id` ?
Because in above question the structure is not made yet. You can see it is how I want it to look like.

Comment: Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800407/4409113) for creating nodes and etc. I thought you already made the current structure however, I'd avoid such structure and just using `Messages` as the root node and then users id with information and contents. (as you can see in the provided picture in the link)

Comment: Thank you for help ! It works. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: You can also accept the answer to resolve this issue for the future searches. Glad to help :) happy coding.